# How to deal with used external IDE HHDs that will no longer be used?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive

I have two external IDE HDDs purchased in 2005 and they are still looking new. The HDDs inside are both Seagate IDE (model: 8t3160021A) 7200rpm 160GB 3.5", and the enclosures are still working fine except that one's power adapter stopped working in the last month and replacing it will cost about $25.

I am going to purchase a new external HDD, probably 1TB or 2TB. I don't think I will need the two external IDE HDDs once I have the new one, so I wonder how to deal with those two external IDE HDDs?

1. Are IDE HDDs still useful these days for some purpose? Is IDE
   completely inferior compared to SATA and other popular ones?
2. If I disassemble the external IDE HDDs and decide to keep the IDE
   HDDs, I wonder how to store them properly?
3. Is there a market for external IDE HDDs or their parts? Who might be willing to buy them?

Comment: Erase and Price them cheap on ebay classifieds, better than them going to the landfill, someone will use them. its surprising how much older PC hardware is still in use and in need of the occasional spare part.

Comment: @Moab: you mean to sell the entire external HDDs, or just the HDDs without the enclosures (one enclosure's power adapter not working any more)?

Comment: I would sell the bare drives, I think there are more people looking for older ide drives than older external drives that are too small for their primary use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My personal recommendation is to backup the data, and destroy the hard drives. Due to the age, it's not reliable anymore, and the interface is not as comparatively well as SATA.

When I have old HDDs, I take them apart with a couple different Torx screw drivers, and get the shiny platters and strong magnets. I have magnets all over in my car, just cause they're awesome. The platters are the shiniest surfaces I have ever seen before.

If you want to keep the drives, make sure they're put in a safe, secure place that won't shake much.

As for sellability? I would never buy IDE unless I absolutely had to. Therefore, I would try eBay after running [dban](https://dban.org) over the drives

Comment: Thanks! Besides that they are awesome, do you have other usages of the platters and magnets that you have taken out?

Comment: Sell the parts to people who are amazed by mirrors and magnets